# Parent window of a popup not reloading

Tags: javascript, popup, parent-child, window.opener

I have opened a popup window and trying to refresh the parent window before closing parent window.

Below is my code. I tried using window.top, top.location, etc but nothing working for me!

Any help?

```
$("#closeit").click(function(){
    opener.location.focus();
    opener.location.reload();
    window.close();
});
```

Comment: `window.opener`, or the alias `opener` as in your example, should have worked. `window.top` and `window.parent` are meant to be used with iframes. Are your main window and popup on the same domain? If not, the browser will not allow the popup to access the main window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to handle the unload event handler in the pop-up and do the reloading in the main window. In the main window, add

```
function popUpClosed() {
    window.location.reload();
}
```

In the pop-up:

```
window.onunload = function() {
    if (window.opener && !window.opener.closed) {
        window.opener.popUpClosed();
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you :) it worked well for me. cannot give +1 as I joined community just now

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the parent object:

```
window.parent.location.reload()
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp

Comment: `window.parent` is meant for frames. See [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.parent).